# Rails .joins() between tables and .where() condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

### Summary

Thanks a lot for your help.
I have a `locations` and `ads` table. Location `has_many :ads`

I would like to make a query of `Location` Model with a `join` with `Ad` Model, to filter entries on parameters of `Location` and `Ad`.

```
@locations = Location.joins(:ads).where(locations: location_params, ads: location_params[:ads_attributes])
```

This is the location_params method (empty fields will be deleted with another method that is working fine).

```
params.require(:location).permit(:country, {:ads_attributes => [:remote, :days]})
```

This is an example of my query. I have a method which remove empty fields from location_params. It works fine.

```
SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" INNER JOIN "ads" 
ON "ads"."location_id" = "locations"."id" 
WHERE "ads_attributes"."remote" = $1  [["remote", "1"]]
```

In this case location_params has the following fields:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"ads_attributes"=>
<ActionController::Parameters {"remote"=>"1"} permitted: true>} permitted: true>
```

This is the result, an empty object even if I have entries with those parameters in my table

```
#<Location::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x3fb83def8190>
```

### Update

1. First Issue - Solved from [Péter Tóth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3941583/p%C3%A9ter-t%C3%B3th-toma)

Solution. Using `.includes(:ads)` for not re-executing the query with `@locations[0].ads`.

```
@locations = Location.joins(:ads).where(locations: {id: 1}, ads: {id: 1})
```

The problem is, when i select from location the `ads`, it will perform again the query and delete the previous filter ads.id = 1.

```
@locations[0].ads
```

The result is not only ad with id=1 will be selected but all ads of that @location[0] will be selected.

1. Second Issue

I am able to execute the query:

```
@locations = Location.joins(:ads).where(locations: {id: 1}, ads: {id: 1})
```

Or

```
@locations = Location.joins(:ads).where(location_params)
```

But not

```
@locations = Location.joins(:ads).where(locations: location_params, ads: ads_params)
```

But this can be solved as follows:
Perform a first query on Location

```
@locations = Location.joins(:ads).where(@location_params.require(:location).permit(:id)).includes(:ads)
```

which returns all locations with those parameters, then I need to filter @locations based on the ads filters. The problem is that I am not able to do the following query.

```
@locations = @locations.joins(:ads).where(ads: @ads_params.require(:ads).permit(:id)).includes(:ads)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to rewrite the query since `ads_attributes` is not a table, Try this

```
ads_params = @ads_params.require(:ads).permit(:id).to_h
location_params = @location_params.require(:location).permit(:id).to_h
@locations = Location.joins(:ads).where(locations: location_params, ads: ads_params)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry I can not select a specific column with `{ country: location_params[:country] }`. There are several fields and there is a method which delete them if they are empty. If `location_params[:country]` is blank then it will be deleted and it will be `nil`. I would like to just input `location_params` to the query without giving a specific column to be selected.

Do you know how to fix the following query so that it will work?  `@locations = Location.joins(:ads).where(locations: new_params, ads: new_params[:ads_attributes])`
Thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer, this should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks RSB, it still does not work. this is location_params `<ActionController::Parameters {"country"=>"IT", "location"=>"Leizpig"} permitted: true>` while this is ads_params `<ActionController::Parameters {"remote"=>"1"} permitted: true>` and the query is empty  `#<Location::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x3f9eeac68e00>`

Comment: I can not figure out how to solve it. I am thinking of doing 2 steps:
1. first I filter everything based on the Location model 2. I filter the result based on the Ad Model. If you have any advice tell me then we edit  your answer with the final answer and I will accept.

Comment: I am thinking maybe the problem is not the query but Association between Location and Ad. I am selecting from Location Model, but Location has_many :ads. Even if i am able to make the query with a join, then when i do location.ads it will loose the filter that i made on Ad

Comment: Do you want to edit your answer with the content of the other discussion? I think also this question should have you as correct answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42760581/rails-where-query-not-working?noredirect=1#comment72637634_42760581

Answer (score 6):

`@locations[0].ads` will fetch all the `ads` for the first location object no matter what. Of course it will only perform the fetch process if they have been not fetched yet. One solution is to side load the `ads`:

```
@locations = Location.joins(:ads).where(locations: {id: 1}, ads: {id: 1}).includes(:ads)
@locations[0].ads
```

This way you can avoid the N + 1 queries problem. But you should use it careful since the `@locations[0].ads.reload` will load all the `ads` no matter what filter you used earlier.

A tip: It depends on what your purpose is, if you need only `ads` according some criteria, then I would suggest to start with `Ad.join(:location).where(...).includes(:location)...`

**Update**

This is working for me if I send `GET /locations?location[country]=IT&ad[remote]=1`:

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @locations = Location.joins(:ads).where(locations: location_filters, ads: ad_filters).includes(:ads)
  end

  private

  def location_filters
    params.require(:location).permit(:country)
  end

  def ad_filters
    params.require(:ad).permit(:remote, :days)
  end
end
```

Or if you don't have all the prams available in each case, then you might want to build a query:

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @locations = Location.joins(:ads).includes(:ads)
    @locations = @locations.where(locations: location_filters) if location_filters.present?
    @locations = @locations.where(ads: ad_filters) if ad_filters.present?
  end

  private

  def location_filters
    params.fetch(:location, {}).permit(:country)
  end

  def ad_filters
    params.fetch(:ad, {}).permit(:remote, :days)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved this specific issue, where I could not do `@locations[0].ads`, but my problem now is getting `@locations` filled. In my case I can not use `id` or a specific parameter, because the fields get deleted with another method when they are blank. So I would like to use the solution of @RSB ,but when I try the query in my console or in debug it does not work.

Comment: Sorry, but the problem was that the parameters needed to be converted .to_h