# Rails .where() query not working

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

Thanks a lot for your help.
I have a `locations` and `ads` table. Location `has_many :ads`
I perform the following query on Location Model.

```
@locations = Location.joins(:ads).where(@location_params.require(:location).permit(:id)).includes(:ads)
```

Then I want to perform an additional query on `@locations` and filter it based on `:ads`

```
@locations = @locations.joins(:ads).where(ads: @ads_params.require(:ads).permit(:id)).includes(:ads)
```

This query does **not** work. It returns an empty object.

```
=> #<Location::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x1e29270>
```

This are the parameters:

1. location_params

   ```
   @location_params.require(:location).permit(:id) 
   <ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>1} permitted: true>
   ```
2. ads_params

   ```
   @ads_params.require(:ads).permit(:id)
   <ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>1} permitted: true>
   ```

It is not permitted to give a specific column input like this:

```
@locations = Location.joins(:ads).where(locations: {id: 1}, ads: {id: 1})
```

I have postgresql, I did not think about using SQL, but I am not sure.

### Query Parameters

I am using rails console to do this query, for testing.

```
@location_params 
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"location"=><ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>1} permitted: false>} permitted: false>


@location_params.require(:location).permit(:id)
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>1} permitted: true>

@ads_params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"ads"=><ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>1} permitted: false>} permitted: false>

@ads_params.require(:ads).permit(:id)
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>1} permitted: true>
```

Comment: Can you write the whole params hash that you see in the server log here

Comment: simply add `binding.pry`, then in the console run `@locations.joins(:ads).where(ads: ads_params).first` and see the invalid PG statement error, which you have to fix.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko @RSB I updated my post for your request. I am testing in the console, I run the code with `.first` and I receive the `TypeError: cant't quote ActionController::Parameters`

Comment: Exactly, you need to convert whitelisted params to hash, edited answer.

Comment: I wrote about the way you're passing the params into query, but was not sure. it was `Location.joins(:ads).where(ads: ads_params.permit!.to_h`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Did you delete your comment? It may be working what you wrote. Just let me know. As it may be working I am close to accepting the correct answer. If RSB query is fixed I will accept his answer in the other older post, as he already helped me with this query. Thanks a lot to everyone

Comment: Andrey - He has already whitelisted params in that method

Comment: @RSB yes, but it was still not a hash object, which AR query is expecting (which you successfully incorporated into your answer after my comment :))

Comment: @Andrey `to_h` is needed as you said, but I think `.permit!` is not needed again. Thanks for your suggestion, you can add your answer.

Comment: @RSB you're right, params has `permitted: true`, thus `permit!` is redundant. There is no sense in adding an answer which will repeat the one already given :)

Comment: @RSB Ok, I test this RSB and if you 2 agree and if it work I will accept your answers. Still I have seen Andrey comment telling me to use the `.to_h` method (also with .permit!). I tested that it worked then he deleted the comment, maybe you 2 found the solution almost at the same time.

Comment: Andrey was the one to suggest `to_h` after your comment, I was a bit late to add saw your comment later on binding.pry result. This is a Rails 5 specific problem though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34949505/rails-5-unable-to-retrieve-hash-values-from-parameter

Comment: Guys, the SO prime goal is to help, since the answer given works, I say accept it, we're glad we helped :) P.S. Always add the environment setup information (Ruby version, Rails version etc :))

Comment: Thanks a lot to both Andrey and RSB. I am accepting your answer RSB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
ads_params = @ads_params.require(:ads).permit(:id).to_h
location_params = @location_params.require(:location).permit(:id).to_h
@locations = Location.joins(:ads).where(locations: location_params, ads: ads_params)
```

Hope that helps!