# Rewhere or unscope a query containing an array condition on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to `rewhere` or `unscope` a query, where the original condition cannot be written using hash condition:

```
Reservation.where('block_id IS NULL OR block_id != ?', 'something')

> SELECT `reservations`.* FROM `reservations` WHERE (block_id IS NULL OR block_id != 'something')
```

Trying to rewhere doesn't work:

```
Reservation.where('block_id IS NULL OR block_id != ?', 'something').rewhere(block_id: 'anything')

> SELECT `reservations`.* FROM `reservations` WHERE (block_id IS NULL OR block_id != 'something') AND `reservations`.`block_id` = 'anything'
```

But this example with `hash condition` would work:

```
Reservation.where.not(block_id: 'something').rewhere(block_id: 'anything')

> SELECT `reservations`.* FROM `reservations` WHERE `reservations`.`block_id` = 'anything'
```

I understand that this is probably because on the `array condition` rails doesn't know which column I'm invoking a where, and therefore `rewhere` won't find anything to replace.

Is there any way to explicitly tell which column I'm filtering in an array condition? or rewrite the first query (IS NULL OR != value) with hash condition?

Note: Please don't suggest `unscoped`, as I'm trying to unscope/rewhere only this specific condition, not the whole query.

Thanks!

Comment: I am of the idea, after the discussions made on SO that you can pass a hash condition for multiple columns, without specifying, but I think I may have misunderstood your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42760581/rails-where-query-not-working

Comment: Thanks, @FabrizioBertoglio. With the hash condition, I'd need to combine a `.where.not` with an `OR IS NULL`. I think this is not possible with rails 4.

Comment: Does `Reservation.where('block_id IS NULL OR block_id != ?', 'something').except(:where).where(block_id: 'anything')` work?

Comment: It does @MarcRohloff, but then it will also remove any other `where` that I might have applied to the query, which is similar to `unscoped` in this case. I'd like to remove only the `where` on `block_id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry it wasn't clear that you had other where clauses that you wanted to keep. You could access the array of where clauses using `relations.values[:where]` and manipulate it, something like:

```
Reservation.where('block_id IS NULL OR block_id != ?', 'something')
           .tap do |relation|
                  # Depending on your version of Rails you can do 
                  where_values = relation.where_values
                  # Or
                  where_values = relation.values[:where]
                  # With the first probably being better
                  where_values.delete_if { |where| ... }
                end
           .where(block_id: 'anything')
```

aka hacking

Comment: I found that `where_values` isn't available in all versions of Rails, although it is a better solution. You might have to use `values[:where]`